# validation for blank values in csv

Tags: php

I want to add following validation while uploading csv file
if any csv string is blank ,it should throw an error
im converting csv to array using the

```
<?
test.csv contains
1,2,3,4
2,,5,6
$csvFile = 'test.csv';  
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);


function readCSV($csvFile)
    {
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }

    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$csvFile = 'test.csv';  
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);

function readCSV($csvFile) {
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $current_line = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        if(in_array('', $current_line) {
            throw new Exception('Some data is missing');
        }
        else {
            $line_of_text[] = $currentLine;
        }
    }

    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking to validate each csv row to make sure no values are empty in the array for that row. If that is correct you can do this:

```
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $currentLine = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $valid = true;
    for each ($currentLine as $currentValue) {
        //validation
        if (empty($currentValue)) {
            // validation
            $valid = false;
        }
    }
    if ($valid) {
        $line_of_text[] = $currentLine;
    }
}
```